# mysql automatic random default integer value

Tags: mysql, random, integer, default

I know that auto_increment assigns a value for a primary key automatically with each new row you insert into a table. Is there some kind of default value you can assign an integer primary key that results in a random number with each new insertion? Something like `DEFAULT_VALUE = FLOOR(RAND() * (1000000-1))` ? I know this is probably a very banal and silly question but I would appreciate any help in advance! Thanks!

Comment: The reason for doing this usually goes something like this... "We're a stationery company. Every time a customer buys something from us we create an invoice with an incrementing id. Unfortunately, this means our competitors can see how well we're doing by just buying very cheap items from us every hour or so. How can we protect ourselves from this?" Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)?

Alternatively, why not let `id` do its thing, `AUTO_INCREMENT` style, and create a secondary column that's generated randomly and indexed `UNIQUE` so it serves as a secondary primary?

Comment: I am still learning more about MySQL. Thanks for the advice on using a second primary key. I did not know that was how it was typically used.

Comment: You normally use `id` internally, for relating data, and some kind of presentation key for display. This could be a slug, a UUID, a random number, a serial like 'Bill#932', or whatever your application requires.

Comment: I did find a way to generate a number automatically so that I don't have to generate the UUID in a request itself. I used the trigger function